# Connecting a Sick laserscanner via ethernet

Tags: sicklms, ubuntu, laserscanner, ubuntu-trusty, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

We're working on our robot running Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS indigo. Right now we are trying to connect a Sick LMS 111 laserscanner via ethernet. We installed the drivers http://wiki.ros.org/LMS1xx and can start the node to do this.
Afterwards we tried to connect to the laserscanner using many ip's (found by ifconfig for example) but any of them gave back this error:

```
[ INFO] [1429170035.841400945]: Connecting to laser at : 192.168.0.1:2111
[ERROR] [1429170163.097305396]: Connection to LMS1xx device failed, retrying in 1 second.
```

To find the port we downloaded the Sopas Engineering Toolbox from Sick. This gave us ip 192.168.0.1 and tcp 2111.
To set the port we adjusted the launch file:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="host" default="192.168.0.1:2112" />
  <node pkg="lms1xx" name="lms1xx" type="LMS1xx_node" output="screen">
    <param name="host" value="$(arg host)" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to get data from the laserscanner?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207220/connecting-a-sick-laserscanner-via-ethernet/) by [Sander](https://answers.ros.org/users/21998/sander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
It is not necessary to indicate port in laser's ip address, just write  `<arg name="host" default="192.168.0.1" />`.
Default port connection is set to 2111, which is the usual port SOPAS gives to sick lms 1xx laser scanners.

If this does not solve the problem, try adjusting your manual ethernet connection to suit a similar address to the laser's one.

---

Originally posted by [danimtb](https://answers.ros.org/users/21901/danimtb/) with karma: 68 on 2015-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sander](https://answers.ros.org/users/21998/sander/) on 2015-05-17**:
You're correct. The problem was that we manually added a connection in Ubuntu with 192.168.0.1 as ip address. The trick was that the ip address has to be different from the ip address from the laserscanner. Thus when we added 192.168.0.2 as ip address on that ethernet port it worked.

**Comment by [danimtb](https://answers.ros.org/users/21901/danimtb/) on 2015-05-17**:
Great to see it worked! I am using Sick LMS100 with LMS1xx node too and I'm able to connect to the laserscanner but after a few minutes the node stops sending data.

Could you tell the ethernet configuration you are using (IP, MASK, GATEWAY)? I suppose your ethernet connection is set to manual. Thx

**Comment by [Sander](https://answers.ros.org/users/21998/sander/) on 2015-05-18**:
On edit connections, click add, go to ethernet tab, set device MAC address to the right ethernet port, got to IPv4 Settings tab, set method to Manual and enter these settings:
Address: 192.168.0.1
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Leave Gateway open and click save.

**Comment by [danimtb](https://answers.ros.org/users/21901/danimtb/) on 2015-05-19**:
Thanks for your comment, now it is working except when I connect my computer to a router via wifi at the same time.

If I disconnect wifi it works great but with wifi connection I have same problem: node connects to lms100 well but after a while it stops sending data...

Did you have this problem?